# Syncswap API endpoint

Tags: exchange-api, endpoint

I've been trying to go through the documentation and discord for syncswap.xyz exchange to find the api endpoint, but could not find anything like that. I'm confused on how people found the it to build code with it, can anyone help me.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://syncswap.gitbook.io/syncswap/smart-contracts/developers